# Handling asynchronous calls in bot framework

Tags: node.js

We are using a Bot configured via Microsoft Bot Framework written in NodeJS. During the execution flow of a dialog, we present the user with certain information and then some server processing is done via SOAP and the result of this SOAP response would be needed before the next waterfall method starts.

In short, we have the below piece of code:

```
bot.dialog('changedefaultlogingroupDialog', [
    async function (session, args, next) {
        wargs[0] = 'change default login group';

        var sourceFile = require('./fetchSharePointUserDetail.js');
        session.privateConversationData.userSharepointEmail = global.DEVSharepointBotRequestorEmailID;
        console.log('\nsession.privateConversationData.userSharepointEmail:'+session.privateConversationData.userSharepointEmail);
        var get_SharepointUserId_args = ['get Sharepoint user id', session.privateConversationData.userSharepointEmail];
        sourceFile.login(get_SharepointUserId_args);

            setTimeout(() => {
                global.DEVSharepointTeamcenterUserID = require('./fetchSharePointUserDetail.js').DEVTeamcenterUserId;
                  console.log('\nglobal.DEVSharepointTeamcenterUserID:'+global.DEVSharepointTeamcenterUserID+'\n');
                  console.log("Request has been made from directline channel by user id <"+global.DEVSharepointTeamcenterUserID+">");
                  session.privateConversationData.requestor_id =  global.DEVSharepointTeamcenterUserID; 
                  session.privateConversationData.create_ques  = session.message.text;
                  next();
              }, 3000);
    },

async function (session, result, next) {

    Do processing here that is dependent on session.privateConversationData.requestor_id

}
```

As you can see from the above example, the setTimeout method is waiting for 3 seconds to have the SOAP response retrieved. While this worked in DEV landscape, it failed in our PRD landscape. So I wanted to know what is the more appropriate way of doing this. Is 'await' a correct case for using in this context?. I am asking this as this is in BOT Framework Context and not sure if that has any side affects.

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Pavan.

Answer (score 0):

Await is the correct way to look at this.

I'm not familiar with the bot framework, but I'm guessing that they asynchronous part of your code happens during the login.

```
await sourceFile.login(get_SharepointUserId_args);
```

Would be where the asynchronous call is.  It could also be in the `fetchSharePointUserDetail.js` 
There is likely a better way to load that file as a module so that you are calling functions on a returned object, rather than returning variables from some code that is obviously executing something.